# How to get rid of a Griffin LCD guard I've attached to my camera and no longer want?

Tags: equipment-protection, equipment-damage, rear-lcd

Immediately after purchasing D5300 last year, I put a hard LCD cover (manufactured by GRIFFIN) on top of the read LCD screen to protect it from scratches. Sounds good though, it started creating problems by not letting my camera's swivel screen lock. Until the screen-guard was unpacked and put on the LCD, I didn't know how thick it is. It looks something like this:

[image]

I want to get rid of the LCD guard. But, seems that the adhesive is so strong, if I apply force t take it out, it can damage the actual LCD. Is there any way out?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor to see if they have removal instructions?

Comment: It's not so known a company.

Comment: https://support.griffintechnology.com/ You should be able to ask there. Not saying you shouldn't come here, someone may stop by and have an answer right off the top of their heads. If they don't, or if you hear back from Girffin, you can post their response here and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a hair dryer to warm up the adhesive enough to soften it up. This is actually the official way to remove the OEM LCD covers on many Canon cameras when they need to be replaced due to scratches. I've done it with a 5D Mark II to replace a busted screen cover. Just be sure to keep the stream of hot air moving and heat up everything evenly without letting one side get too hot. The instructions that come with the replacement part do warn that excessive heat can warp any plastic or electrical components located in the same area!

Comment: The adhesive seems so strong apparently. I wonder if it can be 'softened/loosened' with just a stream of hot air.

Comment: You have to use the hot air to warm the adhesive until it softens. As I've said in the answer, I've personally performed this repair and the adhesive will soften as it is heated.

Comment: When you say "OEM" here, do you mean non-branded replacement parts for the *built-in* screen cover, or do you mean third party add-on products? By definition there can't be an OEM version of something Canon doesn't sell, and they don't sell these, do they?

Comment: I mean the OEM built in screen cover that is installed by Canon at the factory when the camera is manufactured and that is replaceable without requiring replacement of the LCD screen itself on some Canon models. Canon sells the replacement part for the models that allow replacement of only the cover. The 5D Mark II is one such model. The 5D Mark III is not one of those models.

Comment: The Canon part number for the LCD cover window of the Canon 5D Mark II is CB3-4948-000 and is available from a number of resellers, many that are Canon authorized repair centers. Canon does not offer parts for sale directly to retail customers.